# Can "splooge" be considered a form of onomatopoeia?

Tags: word-choice, grammar

I know I've heard that sound. I can't quite remember where. If you Google it, it refers you to ejaculation. I did find one reference that identified it as a verb and a noun, but no mention of onomatopoeia. Does it qualify?

Comment: If that's an approximation to the noise you hear when someone ejaculates nearby then yes, surely, it is onomatopoeic.  Otherwise not.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark - 'the noise you hear when someone ejaculates nearby' sadly, that is something I have never experienced.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark “If that’s an approximation of the noise you hear when someone ejaculates nearby”, you need to call a doctor, an exorcist, or both.

Comment: It's not a noise I've ever heard in the circumstances @DanBron and I tend to agree with your diagnosis 

Answer (score 6):

It's not necessarily onomatopoeic. **If** whatever is being talked about using *splooge* (as any part of speech) made a noise that sounded like "splooge" (or could be described that way, whatever the actual acoustics were), **then** it would be onomatopoeia, because that term refers only to words that **sound** like what they mean, like *cock-a-doodle-do, [clunk](https://websites.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/kl-chart.pdf),* or *smooch*.

*Splooge* is an example of a much bigger and more widespread phenomenon than mere onomatopoeia. It turns out that virtually all English words beginning with *SPL*- have a [phonosemantic](https://websites.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/#mono) relation. In formal terms, they all refer to some kind of one-dimensional transition to two-dimensionality, including streams of fluid moving downward (think waterfall). Here's the [breakdown](https://websites.umich.edu/%7Ejlawler/spl.pdf):

***SPL*-** 13 of 14 coherent = 93% coherence
Transition of 1-Dimensional Origin to 2-Dimensional Result 11

- a. Origin Focus
  Origin: 1-D Rigid object(s) *splay split spline splice splint splinter* 6
  Result: 2-D Rigid (composed of connected 1-D objects)
- b. Result Focus (impact of fluid stream)
  Origin: 1-D Fluid (perceived as stream) *splotch splash splat splatter splutter* 5
  Result: 2-D Fluid (random impact residue, usually on 2-D)
- c. Metaphoric fluid transition: *spleen splurge* 2
- Residue: *splendor* 1

*Splooge* (which wasn't in my database) would fit under (b).